# RadioButton, Transfer Int to another Activity

Tags: android

Trying to make radio button, Transfer an Integer and set it in TextView in another Activity 
after click button.

This is A activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button B = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
}
    public void Set(View v){
  RadioButton RBB = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RB1);
  TextView T1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.R1);
  if(RBB.isChecked()== true){
      Intent IL = new Intent(this,Transfer.class);
      int C = 10;
      IL.putExtra("C",C);
      startActivity(IL);
  }}
    }
```

This is Activity B :

```
public class Transfer extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.transfer);
    TextView TB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    Bundle extra =getIntent().getExtras();
    int Y = extra.getInt("C");
    TB.setText(Y);


}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
TB.setText(Y);
```

to

```
TB.setText(Integer.toString(Y));
```

When you pass an integer to a TextView, it thinks it's a resource id in your strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use `TB.setText(Y+"");` in `Transfer` activity.